# dynamic function calls in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodeJS, and right now i'm writing a small service that connects to an external api.
this api has several types of objects, and for each object there are several types of functions.
i want my service to query this api, but what i want is that the queries will be defined each in it's own json file, so for future use, people can add/remove/change these queries.

example for a json file:

```
{
  "object": "foo",
  "function": "bar",
  "params": {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "2"
  }
}
```

the object is 'foo', the is 'bar', and the params will be passed as a whole json object, so i don't really care about this part.

how can i create the object 'foo', and then call the function 'bar'?

Comment: is the `bar` function already defined in the code?

Comment: `var foo=new foo(); foo['bar'].call(foo, params)`?

Comment: foo and bar are already defined in the API. i just need test.json to tell me which object i need to create, and then witch function to call (with the given params).

Comment: @WiredPrairie Why do you use `foo['bar'].call(foo, params)`? It would be the same as just writing `foo['bar'](params)`. Or did you mean `.apply` but that would only work with arrays.

Comment: In fact, I did. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding things... say you load the query values like this... (assuming possibly minor changes to make this work, or using another method to load the file contents up as a string and then parse it etc.....)

```
var fileJSON = require('./test.json');
var meta = JSON.parse(fileJSON);
```

... then assuming that the "foo" object is a field on the current method's context (i.e. this) ... (which might not even be correct) you "might" do something funky like this...

```
this[meta.object][meta.function](meta.params);
```

i.e. get "foo" object off of context, get the "function" function off of that object, and we call it passing in the params as an object as you mentioned (whether you need this I'm unsure)

**Warning:**
 - I'm not sure if the "foo" being a field on the current object (this) would be correct but I'm sure you can adjust for this... You just need to change *this* to whatever the object is that has the "foo" object in a field or something like that i.e construct the instance of "foo"... not knowing how things are structured this is the best example I think I can give you.
 - I'm unsure if nodejs (v8) will choke on the .object and .function... you might have to go like this instead

```
this[meta["object"]][meta["function"]](meta.params);
```

- This is untested, I don't have time to test, but I'm hoping that in the little time I have it might at least aid you a somewhat. If it doesn't then no matter. Hope it helps!

Comment: Why not just writing `this[meta.object][meta.function](meta.params);`? `meta.function` will still be called in context of `this[meta.object]`.

Comment: Why not.. because I was tired when I wrote it! 
:o)

Comment: Well `[...] call() then ensures the context is still "foo" inside the method [...]` is then a little bit misleading, while it is not wrong, it sounds like it is required in that case ;)

Comment: Yup, agreed, I've removed the code. Just going to updated anything else... Thanks!

Comment: from what i have seen v8 does currently have not problems with `.function`, `.object`, `.new`, ... and afaik it is valid from the specs, IDEs sometimes don't like some of those (like nodeclipse which is going crazy when seeing some of these).

Comment: @t.niese - That's what I thought too. I've seen IE break (from IE8 down I think) but don't remember this being an issue in Chrome, but that was a while ago now, and wasn't completely sure I was remembering right at the time I wrote above. Another good bit of feedback! Cheerz.